# Numpy.argmax() on certain axis in 2D matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, flatten, argmax

I'm currently working on creating a ranking algorithm to rank relationships between students.  In my NxN matrix F:
    F[i, j] refers to the relationship between student i and student j. The higher the value, the stronger the relationship.

My problem is such.  For creating a cluster of k students, I first choose the argmax of F.  If the argmax returns index (i, j), I add students i and j to my cluster.  I then want to find the argmax of F along axis i and j, and take the larger of the two as the next student in my cluster.  I then repeat this process along the axis of each student in the cluster until I have k students in my cluster.

Where I am confused:
    numpy.argmax() takes a flattened axis as the argument for which axis to search through.  How do I flatten axis i and j so that I can do numpy.argmax(F, flattenedAxis)?

I'm a relative beginner to Python, so this probably has an easy answer whose existence I was unaware of.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will give you the index of the largest element in matrix F.

```
ind = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(F),F.shape)
```

This will give you the row number of the largest element in column j.

```
max_row_in_col_j = np.argmax(F[:,j])
```

This will give you the column number of the largest element in row i.

```
max_col_in_row_i = np.argmax(F[i,:])
```